# How to avoid Selenium detection or change approach

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

### Goal

I want to create a bot that would automatically edit products one by one on an online shop:

1. Open main list of products
2. Click on "EDIT" on n product (new window opens)

   - on opened window click some button, wait for page load, enter some text and select const that pops up
   - click on "SAVE"
   - exit the window
3. iterate product
4. go to step 2

### Problem

Currently my problem is that I get captcha and/or blocked even if I just do `driver.get("link")` and use the selenium browser as human. I suppose the problem is with meta data that I send to the website.

### My attempt

My final code to "mask" selenium was sourced from different stackoverflow's threads:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from time import sleep

added_product = "PAKIET OCHRONY - GWARANCJA NA 2 LATA"

ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.chrome
print(user_agent)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


driver.get("https://allegro.pl")

driver.maximize_window()
sleep(1000)
```

The thing is that I can be there and monitor what's happening on the screen, I just want at least partial automation. What I thought would be good approach is to use my default "human" browser and make a script that would click inside of it. What I lack is knowledge of some kind of technology that can do this.

### TL;DR

I need to do simple clicks/text input over windows that open whenever I iterate through products.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Selenium gets detected by anti-bot services. You would need to use a modified Selenium, such as [SeleniumBase UC Mode](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/uc_mode.md), to bypass detection.

After `pip install seleniumbase`, you can run the following script without getting detected on that site:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://allegro.pl", 5)
    breakpoint()
```

Once you're on that site, you can use `driver.uc_click(selector)` to click things carefully if the site still tries to detect you. There's a lot more documentation on the [SeleniumBase GitHub Page](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase).

Comment: Tested yours as well, this is my code: https://pastebin.com/J5iDwPcf I have no idea what else can I do, even if I complete captcha puzzle slider by my hand I get blocked.. I would appreciate your help very much, it would save me litterally ~80 hours per month.

Comment: There's a `driver.uc_click(selector)` method in SeleniumBase. Use it if you need to click undetected. Example: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/raw_turnstile.py

Comment: Well I changed the `click` to `driver.uc_click`, but now the website from start gives me captcha to solve and blocks me no matter in what way I complete it. What is strange for me, is that I can login on the website through my everyday browser (brave) after I complete captcha. Why is that?

Comment: I got the code to be somewhat working, I still have to solve puzzle slider captcha but I think that's rather fine. May I ask you to explain to me a bit more about `uc` methods and how should I utilize them? Also, is there a documentation with of all functions listed? I'm not sure how to navigate through the code and what I used so far is rightclick -> Go to -> Implementation and tried to work out what is going there. In general, can you please provide me some tips/advice or anything I should consider to make this bot stable and fail-safe.

Comment: Here's a link to the UC Mode docs (which includes a link to a YouTube tutorial): https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/uc_mode.md

Comment: I actually watched it already when you posted your answer, I am having problem of detecting on different stages of clicking and wanted to get some advice on how should I configure the bot so it will look human - you said that I should fit it to the website and that it will take some time but I have no idea what should I try here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the undetected selenium package available on pypi:

https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/

Or, a popular github repo that I usually use:

https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

This is an optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io Automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it

Comment: Still gets detected. This is the code I was trying it with: https://pastebin.com/Q8fJw4pz

Comment: @Janekk Why don't you try adding a user-agent header? Please copy the user-agent that shows up while manually using the website.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - I suppose you want me to check what's my user agent on my default "human" browser (brave) and put it into the bot through code before it interacts with the website?
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36` This is the user agent from my default Brave browser.
I also did `sb.open_url("site-that-checks-useragent")` and both are the 1 to 1 the same, as well as screen resolution, browser, browser version etc.

Comment: I also tried to just open the site and make the bot wait until I login and navigate and only then try to click "edit" button next to first product but I can't even get there, website blocks me after few clicks even though I'm doing it by hand.

Comment: fake-useragent doesn't work as well